# Show email addresses as hyperlink except the comma

Tags: visualforce, html

Email Address : bob.marley@abc.com , sia@cheapthrills.com

Currently we are displaying as plain text.
Requirement : To display each address as clickable hyperlink .

Current code:

```
<tr>
    <th class="blue">
      To Address
    </th>
    <td class="wrap class" data-label="To Address">
       {!businessEmail.ToAddress}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please provide some idea as how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store them as a list{string} or a set{string} in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `ToAddress` in a list of string, may be by splitting into.
Then use apex repeat to render link for each of them as below.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!toAddressList}" var="email"
<a href="{!'mailto:' + email}">{!email}</a>
</apex:repeat>
```